# Remove last item of a list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a simple unordered list and I would like to remove the last item on click of a button. I read somewhere that pop(); will do this but I am having trouble getting it working.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<button id="remove">remove item</button>

<ul id="list">
    <li><input type="text"></li>
    <li><input type="text"></li>
    <li><input type="text"></li>
    <li><input type="text"></li>
    <li><input type="text"></li>
</ul>

var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
var removeButton = document.getElementById("remove");

removeButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);

function removeItem() {
    listItems.pop();
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

Uncaught TypeError: listItems.pop is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.removeItem

Which is weird because when I type listItems in the console I am getting the correct array:

listItems
(7) [li, li, li, li, li, li, li]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1fwk8vp/)

Anyone have any suggestions? I dont need to use .pop() any method that works will be fine

Comment: You are only affecting the array, what about affecting your DOM?

Comment: It is not an array. It is a NodeList

Comment: I would do: const list = document.getElementById("myList"); const lastItem = list.querySelector('li:last-child'); lastItem.remove();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pop` is an array function. You'll have to remove the list item like this:

```
function removeItem() {
    var last = listItems[listItems.length - 1];
    last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
}
```

**Note 1:** We don't need to decrement `listItems.length` because it's a live HTMLCollection (returned by `getElementsByTagName`) that reflects the DOM (if an element is removed from the DOM then it gets automatically removed from the collection).

**Note 2:** You may want to check if the collection is empty before attempting to remove the last item (which won't exist if it's empty). Check the example bellow to see how.

**Example:**

```js
var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
var removeButton = document.getElementById("remove");

removeButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);

function removeItem() {
    if(listItems.length === 0) return;           // if there is no items in listItems then quit the function (don't attempt to remove what doesn't exist)

    var last = listItems[listItems.length - 1];
    last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
}
```

```html
<button id="remove">remove item</button>

<ul id="list">
    <li><input type="text"></li>
    <li><input type="text"></li>
    <li><input type="text"></li>
    <li><input type="text"></li>
    <li><input type="text"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The function getElementsByTagName returns an HTMLCollection which isn't an array.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

```html
<button id="remove">remove item</button>

<ul id="list">
    <li><input type="text">1</li>
    <li><input type="text">2</li>
    <li><input type="text">3</li>
    <li><input type="text">4</li>
    <li><input type="text">5</li>
</ul>


<script>


var removeButton = document.getElementById("remove");

removeButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);

function removeItem() {
    var list=document.getElementById("list");
    var listItems = list.getElementsByTagName("li");

    var last=listItems[listItems.length-1];
    list.removeChild(last);
}

</script>
```

Comment: ah gotcha i didnt know that

Comment: No problem. Working code example attached.

Comment: thank you sir, i gave you an upvote